# Anaconda will not run

Tags: python, anaconda

I've installed Anaconda 3, version 2020.02 (current version straight from the website, 64 bit), and cannot figure out how to run it. When I search (on Windows) for Anaconda prompt or Anaconda navigator, I cannot find either. When I try to run any commands like conda init or anaconda-navigator on the command line, it says 'conda is not recognized as an internal or external command'. Yet it did install successfully (supposedly); the installed Anaconda3 files are where they should be. I have added the proper filepath to my system PATH variable, and added Anaconda3/Scripts to the PATH variable as well; neither of these make a difference. Typing 'where conda' on command line results in 'INFO: Could not find files for the given patterns'. I have uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled an earlier version, and this does not work either. What next steps should I take to try to get Anaconda to run?

Comment: check  under  c:\programdata\anaconda3  whether you see any thing like this

Comment: Anything like what? Also, it's in C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3

Comment: do you see shortcut  like this  under that folder 

   Anaconda Navigator (Anaconda3)

Comment: The Anaconda3 folder does not have any Anaconda Navigator subfolders, and it only has two shortcuts - one is _conda, which does nothing, and the other is the uninstall shortcut.

Comment: Just to be sure, please try reinstalling..

Comment: I've reinstalled 5 times now - two of which were older versions of Anaconda, and 3 of which were the current version but with different installation folders and having it automatically set or not set the path variable. Reinstalling doesn't seem to help at all, unfortunately. And I made sure to unset and reset the path variables before each installation.

Comment: @Obor Are you sure you had removed all traces of previous Anaconda installations? Did you use `anaconda-clean` ?

Comment: "anaconda-clean is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Answer (score 0):

Install Anaconda and don't change any of the default settings. This will install Anaconda in your user profile and add the `c:\users\user_name\AppData\Anaconda3\condabin` folder to your system path. But before you can actually use Anaconda, you'll need to activate an environment. Either use the Anaconda prompt shortcut or open a cmd shell and type `conda activate`. If the the prompt doesn't change to `(base) C:\users\user_name>` Anaconda won't work. Adding `../Anaconda3/Scripts` to the PATH simply isn't sufficient. If necessary go to the `c:\users\user_name\AppData\Anaconda3\condabin` folder and run `conda init` again.

Comment: @Obor :  Would you please consider replying to your post. Voluntarily helping you was some effort. So I guess I can ask for a little respect ..